# How to avoid too many nested if when operating on optional UIViewController array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `UIPageViewController`, which has a optional `UIViewController` array.

```
pageViewController.viewControllers
```

I notice that, whenever I need to perform some operation on it, I need to write many levels (4) of `if` check.

```
  // TODO: How can we improve this code?
  //
  // Logic: We will call setViewControllers, if viewControllers is null, or empty, or 1st element of
  // viewControllers.pageIndex is not equal to self.selectedTabIndex
  if let viewControllers = self.pageViewController.viewControllers {
      if viewControllers.count > 0 {
          if let pageIndexable = viewControllers[0] as? PageIndexable {
              if pageIndexable.pageIndex != self.selectedTabIndex {
                  self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: self.selectedTabIndex)!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
                  self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
              }
          }
      } else {
          self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: self.selectedTabIndex)!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
          self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
      }
  } else {
      self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: self.selectedTabIndex)!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
      self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
  }
```

I have a feeling that I might be using **optional** the wrong way, due to too many level of `if` statement.

Can you suggest a way for me to improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about when you *don't* want to call `setViewControllers`. That is when the following is false:

> `viewControllers` is nil, or empty, or `viewControllers[0].pageIndex != self.selectedTabIndex`

Using De Morgan's Law, we can see that it the negation of that is:

> `viewControllers` is not nil, and not empty, and `viewControllers[0].pageIndex == self.selectedTabIndex`

Wiring that in an if statement, we get:

```
if let vcs = self.pageViewController.viewControllers,
   let firstVC = vcs.first as? PageIndexable, // this checks for non-empty
   firstVC.pageIndex == self.selectedTabIndex {
   // do stuff
} else {
  self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: self.selectedTabIndex)!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
  self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
// do other stuff
```

If the method would return immediately after doing `setViewControllers` and `scrollToItem` (i.e. you don't have any code in the `// do other stuff` position), then you can use a `guard` statement instead:

```
guard let vcs = self.pageViewController.viewControllers,
   let firstVC = vcs.first as? PageIndexable,
   firstVC.pageIndex == self.selectedTabIndex else {
   self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: self.selectedTabIndex)!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
   self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
   return
}
// do stuff
```

As Alexander said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63785806/how-to-avoid-too-many-nested-if-when-operating-on-optional-uiviewcontroller-arra/63785878?noredirect=1#comment112794625_63785878), you can also do this in a single expression:

```
if !((self.pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? PageIndexable)?.pageIndex == self.selectedTabIndex) {

   self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: self.selectedTabIndex)!], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
   self.tabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

}
```

But I think the intention is less clear this way.

Comment: In this case it works out to be much uglier, but I think it's worth knowing that optionals have a bunch of APIs for solving situations like this using a single expression. In this case, it woudl be `self.pageViewController.viewControllers.first.map { $0 as? PageIndexable } == self.selectedTabIndex`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That gave me an idea. See the edit. You don't actually need `map`, do you? You could just chain the optionals all the way through.

Comment: Optional chaining is equivalent to `flatMap` (which works just as well, given that non-optionals implicitly promote to optionals when necessary), but it means you have to have your expression in parenths, which requires you to put an opening `(` way before the `)`. `.map { $0 as? PageIndexable }` keeps the "pipeline" style of it. I usually style it with one `.something { }` per line, which makes it quite tidy. I prefer it over `(` and `) ` that are far spread apart